# Division in fraction calculator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a fraction calculator in python using a class function:

```
class Frac:
    def _simplify(self, num, den, sign):
        a = abs(num)
        b = abs(den)
        while a % b != 0:
            a, b = b, a%b
        return (abs(num) // b *sign, abs(den) // b)
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator = 1):
        self.numerator, self.denominator = numerator, denominator

        if (numerator < 0 and denominator >= 0) or (numerator >= 0 and denominator < 0):
            sign = -1
        else:
            sign = 1
        (self.numerator, self.denominator) = self._simplify(numerator, denominator, sign)

    def __add__(self, other):
        num = (self.numerator * other.denominator) + (self.denominator * other.numerator)
        den = self.denominator * other.denominator
        return Frac(num, den)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        num = (self.numerator * other.denominator) - (self.denominator * other.numerator)
        den = self.denominator * other.denominator
        return Frac(num, den)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        num = self.numerator * other.numerator
        den = self.denominator * other.denominator
        return Frac(num, den)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        num = self.numerator * other.denominator
        den = self.denominator * other.numerator
        return Frac(num, den)

    def __radd__(self, n):
        return self.__add__(Frac(n))

    def __rmul__(self, n):
        return self.__mul__(Frac(n))
```

It works fine until I place an integer first in division:

```
print(1 / Frac(1,2)) #returns TypeError: unsupported operand type
```

Is there a way I can work through this? I had the same problem with `__add__` but solved it using `__radd__`.

Comment: Why not [`__rtruediv__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rtruediv__) (just as you did with `add` and `mul`)?

Comment: I think the problem is that 1 is not of type Frac, so you to cast 1 to Frac

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know that __rtruediv__ existed... Thank you!!

Comment: Basically all binary operations have their `r-operation` equivalents... Check the link I provided

Comment: @Stefan well I have to use this on functions like lambda x: 6/x+2 where x is a Frac